# sqlite3 compound index usage for LIKE and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-like

I can't seem to get sqlite3 to not use a TEMP B-TREE with a compound index for a query with a LIKE clause and a GROUP BY clause. Seems to only use the index for the WHERE clause. I've tried making the index with all combinations with COLLATE NOCASE in the index since LIKE is case insensitive.

Example would be the following with an index on foo, boo.

```
SELECT foo, boo FROM mytable WHERE foo LIKE 'hi%' GROUP BY boo;
```

Also tried using a subquery such as

```
SELECT foo, boo FROM (SELECT foo, boo FROM mytable WHERE foo LIKE 'hi%') GROUP BY boo;
```

Interesting to note is that ORDER BY works in the similar subquery case above but also does not work with the straight query.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is your schema, specifically your index? The order of columns in the index is important. I get a covering index scan by using `CREATE INDEX mytable_idx2 ON mytable(boo, foo);`

Comment: I've tried all combinations.


    `CREATE INDEX mytable_idx1 ON mytable(boo COLLATE NOCASE, foo);`
    `CREATE INDEX mytable_idx2 ON mytable(boo, foo COLLATE NOCASE);`
    `CREATE INDEX mytable_idx3 ON mytable(boo COLLATE NOCASE, foo COLLATE NOCASE);`
   `CREATE INDEX mytable_idx4 ON mytable(boo, foo);`

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(foo, boo, [...]);
> CREATE INDEX bfi ON mytable(boo, foo COLLATE NOCASE);
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT foo, boo FROM mytable WHERE foo LIKE 'hi%' GROUP BY boo;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE mytable USING COVERING INDEX bfi
```

Comment: Are you on a specific version of sqlite3?

Comment: Thanks, for anyone that doesn't spot it, the group by column is actually first in the index. Strange I think but there you go!